# how can move rectangle patch with click mouse python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to know how can I move the rectangle patch when I click anywhere with the mouse ? 
in the code below the rectangle is fixed I just need to move it every time I click with the mouse somewhere ,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

x=y=0.1
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
patch= ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.5, 0.5,
    alpha=1, fill=None,label='Label'))


plt.show()
```

maybe i need to use "motion_notify_event" to connect mouse to rectangle but id'ont know how i can use this function !

my second question is how to get this type of rectangle "selection icon" on the image with matplotlib or if possible to customize the rectangle patch !

[image]

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the rectangle around you can use a simple function that connects to a "button press event" via `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', <function_name>)` and re-defines the x, y origin coordinates of the rectangle. I have shifted those by half the width and height of the rectangle, so that the point you click on will be in its centre.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def on_press(event):
    xpress, ypress = event.xdata, event.ydata
    w = rect.get_width()
    h = rect.get_height()
    rect.set_xy((xpress-w/2, ypress-h/2))

    ax.lines = []   
    ax.axvline(xpress, c='r')
    ax.axhline(ypress, c='r')

    fig.canvas.draw() 

x = y = 0.1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press)

rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.1, 0.1, alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')

ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

As for the prettyfying of the rectangle, have a look at the 
[matplotlib patches](https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html) or the [gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) and see if you find something suitable. I have added a crosshair with red lines as an alternative.

Comment: the question is to connect rectangle with mouse when i click somewhere with click mouse the rectangle is moved cause in your code is can't move

Comment: I added a line so that it should work even if matplotlib's interactive mode is off. Try now.