# how i can get cursor coordinate and using mouse position in other panel in wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am trying to put a cursor and rectangle patch that can moved and  that can display the coordinates or rather pixel of an image select and display on another panel Paneltwo in the textctrl
each time I move the mouse ( automatically rectangel) the pixels of each point are displayed on the other panel

the first problem that the rectangle can't moved with mouse !
the second that what i need to do is when the rectangle moved with mouse i can visualize the pixel or position of mouse ( rectangle) in panel two textctrl !
how can I do that ?

that part of code :

```
 import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi,cos
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,name="Main", size = (600,400))
        self.Panel = Panel(self)




class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(parent=self)
        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.panel_two,1,wx.EXPAND)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel)
        sizer.Add(canvas_sizer)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel du graphique matplotlib """
    def __init__(self, parent , size=(200,250)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(4,3))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size
        self.parent = parent
        t = arange(0.5, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = cos(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)



     #can'tmove rectangel with mouse    
    def on_press(self,event):
        xpress, ypress = event.xdata, event.ydata
        w = rect.get_width()
        h = rect.get_height()
        rect.set_xy((xpress-w/2, ypress-h/2))

        ax.lines = []   
        ax.axvline(xpress, c='b')
        ax.axhline(ypress, c='b')

        self.fig.canvas.draw()


        self.fig = plt.figure

        self.axes = plt.subplot(111)
        self.axes.imshow(t,s)

        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',on_press)


        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x,y),0.01,0.01,linewidth=1,edgecolor='g',facecolor='none')

        self.axes.add_patch(rect)

        self.plt.show()

class PanelTwo(wx.Panel): #here when i need to visualize pixel and coordinator cursor
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=(200,250))

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN|wx.TE_READONLY|
                                wx.TE_RICH2, size=(200,170), pos = (40,20))

        lbl = wx.StaticText(self,label="Coordinato cursor & Pixel " , pos=(40,0))

app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

THANK YOU

Comment: Without context or code, this is not a valid question.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony i edit my question thank you for help

Comment: @RolfofSaxony i edit my question

Comment: Yes you have and it is still unclear what it is that you want. What do you mean by "visualise the pixel or position of the mouse". Do you want to see an image of a single pixel? Do you want the position of the mouse or the rectangle. Or, do you want to display that part of the image, that the rectangle is currently covering. As I said code AND context.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony what i need is to move rectangle with mouse and after is to show the posiition of rectangle  patch ( pixel and x y position) in  PanelTwo i'm traying to move the rectangle like that but is can't move see example here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271104/how-can-move-rectangle-patch-with-click-mouse-python3/56272388?noredirect=1#comment99169570_56272388] here the rectangle is move with mouse  but when i add plot or image is can't move !? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it moves you in the right direction.
Note: I have no idea how you are going to retrieve the pixel position from that plot.
Perhaps someone else, who actually knows what they are doing with matplotlib, because I certainly don't, can help with that.

```
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi,cos
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.patches as patches

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,name="Main", size = (800,400))
        self.Panel = Panel(self)

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(parent=self)
        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.panel_two,1,wx.EXPAND)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel)
        sizer.Add(canvas_sizer)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel du graphique matplotlib """
    def __init__(self, parent , size=(200,250)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(4,3))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size
        self.parent = parent
        t = arange(0.5, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = cos(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        x = y = 0.2
        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.4, 0.4, alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.axes.plot()

    def on_press(self, click):
        x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
        self.parent.panel_two.Update(x1,y1)
        self.rect.set_x(x1 - 0.2) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the X click point
        self.rect.set_y(y1 - 0.2) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the Y click point
        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()

class PanelTwo(wx.Panel): #here when i need to visualize pixel and coordinator cursor
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=(300,250))

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH2, size=(200,170))

        lbl = wx.StaticText(self,label="Coordinato cursor & Pixel ")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,10)
        sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def Update(self,x1,y1):
        self.text_ctrl.SetValue("Mouse click at;\nX "+str(x1)+"\nY "+str(y1))

app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: oh i'm sorry what I meant is not the pixels I was wrong it's more the rows and column and the coordinates  ,!

Comment: Does that plot have discrete rows and columns?

Comment: i have question when i select zoom inside this rectangle is not show me the area inside rectangle why ? if you have any idea ?  thank you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618737/error-when-select-and-show-zoom-inside-rectangle-patch]