# how use artists with patch rectangle to move 2 retcngale in same time

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

i use rectangle patch in two  zoom panel1 and zoom panel 2
the idea is to have to rectangle patch in to panel the two rectangle can move in the same time when i move the rectangle in zooom 1 is move in the same time and same area in the zoom panel 2

how can i use rectangle artist with matplotlib in this exemple

```
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi,cos
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.patches as patches

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,name="Main", size = (800,800))
        self.Panel = Panel(self)
       

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        self.zoom_panel=Zoom(parent=self)
        self.zoom_panel2=Zoom2(parent=self)
        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.zoom_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.zoom_panel2,1,wx.EXPAND)
        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel)
        sizer.Add(canvas_sizer)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel du graphique matplotlib """
    def __init__(self, parent , size=(200,350)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(4,4))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size
        self.parent = parent
        t = arange(0.5, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = cos(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        x = y = 0.02
        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.4,0.4,edgecolor='g', alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.axes.plot()

    def on_press(self, click):
        x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
        zx1 = x1 - 0.2
        zy1 = y1 - 0.2
        zx2 = x1 + 0.2
        zy2 = y1 + 0.2
        self.rect.set_x(x1 - 0.2) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the X click point
        self.rect.set_y(y1 - 0.2) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the Y click point


        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.zoom_axes=[zx1,zx2,zy1,zy2]
        self.parent.zoom_panel.Update(self)
        self.parent.zoom_panel2.Update(self)

        

class Zoom(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=(200,200))
        self.Show()
    def Update(self,parent):
        #Load axis values of the selected rectangle
        zoom_axes=parent.zoom_axes

        #duplicate the plot from the main panel
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(4,4))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        #Apply axis of drawn rectangle to the plot
        self.axes.axis(zoom_axes)
        t = arange(0.5, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = cos(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        x = y = 0.01
        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.02, 0.02,edgecolor='g', alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.axes.plot()


        
    def on_press(self, click):
        x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
        zx1 = x1 - 0.01
        zy1 = y1 - 0.01
        zx2 = x1 + 0.01
        zy2 = y1 + 0.01
        self.rect.set_x(x1 - 0.01) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the X click point
        self.rect.set_y(y1 - 0.01) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the Y click point
        

        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.zoom_axes=[zx1,zx2,zy1,zy2]

class Zoom2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=(200,200))
        self.Show()
    def Update(self,parent):
        #Load axis values of the selected rectangle
        zoom_axes=parent.zoom_axes

        #duplicate the plot from the main panel
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(4,4))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        #Apply axis of drawn rectangle to the plot
        self.axes.axis(zoom_axes)
        t = arange(0.5, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = cos(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        x = y = 0.01
        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.02, 0.02,edgecolor='g', alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.axes.add_artist(self.rect)
        
        self.axes.plot()

        
    def on_press(self, click):
        x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
        zx1 = x1 - 0.01
        zy1 = y1 - 0.01
        zx2 = x1 + 0.01
        zy2 = y1 + 0.01
        self.rect.set_x(x1 - 0.01) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the X click point
        self.rect.set_y(y1 - 0.01) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the Y click point
        

        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.zoom_axes=[zx1,zx2,zy1,zy2]
       
       

app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

thank you all

Comment: Your CanvasPanel, Zoom and Zoom2 do not know about each other so they can't communicate. There are 2 ways to fix it. First simple one is to add functions like "bindSubordinatePanel" and "notifySubordinatePanel" to CanvasPanel and Zoom and call notify after every click or other change. The other is the classic listener approach where CanvasPanel has an "addListener" function that adds a Listener object or just any function to a list and on every change it calls all attached listeners or functions, while other views after initialization. Ex: `canv_panel.addListener(lambda x:zoom_pan.change(x)`

Comment: Ran out of comment length, if the explanation was unclear I can expand or add a full example later.

Comment: @IcedLance if you can add example please cause is not clear thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes made:

- Added communication between 2 Zoom panels. Each can have a subscriber added by `add_subscriber(subscriber_name, action_to_make)` and every time one of them pressed it'll call all `action_to_make(click)`.
- As Zoom and Zoom2 are basically 2 instances of same class (had identical code) I've removed a definition of the 2nd class and made `zoom_panel` and `zoom_panel2` different instances of same class.
- Changed Zoom to only instantiate Figure and Rectangle and all that only once and updating them instead of creating a new instance and placing it atop the old one.

```
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi,cos
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.patches as patches

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,name="Main", size = (1000,800))
        self.Panel = Panel(self)


class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        self.zoom_panel=Zoom(parent=self)
        self.zoom_panel2=Zoom(parent=self)

        self.zoom_panel.add_subscriber("zoom_panel2", self.zoom_panel2.on_notified)
        self.zoom_panel2.add_subscriber("zoom_panel", self.zoom_panel.on_notified)

        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.zoom_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.zoom_panel2,1,wx.EXPAND)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel)
        sizer.Add(canvas_sizer)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel du graphique matplotlib """
    def __init__(self, parent , size=(200,350)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(4,4))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size
        self.parent = parent
        t = arange(0.5, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = cos(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        x = y = -0.2
        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.4,0.4,edgecolor='g', alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.axes.plot()

    def on_press(self, click):
        x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
        zx1 = x1 - 0.2
        zy1 = y1 - 0.2
        zx2 = x1 + 0.2
        zy2 = y1 + 0.2
        self.rect.set_x(x1 - 0.2) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the X click point
        self.rect.set_y(y1 - 0.2) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the Y click point


        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.zoom_axes=[zx1,zx2,zy1,zy2]
        self.parent.zoom_panel.Update(self)
        self.parent.zoom_panel2.Update(self)



class Zoom(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=(200,200))
        self.Show()
        self.subscriber_list = {}
        #init figure&canvas
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(4,4))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axes.axis([-0.2,0.2,-0.2,0.2]) # set default display window
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        #add rectangle
        x = y = 0.01
        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 0.02, 0.02,edgecolor='g', alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)

        #first display
        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()

    def Update(self,parent):
        #Load axis values of the selected rectangle
        zoom_axes=parent.zoom_axes

        #clear Axes
        self.axes.clear()

        #Apply axis of drawn rectangle to the plot
        self.axes.axis(zoom_axes)



        #draw same plot as on the main panel
        t = arange(0.5, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = cos(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s, 'C0')

        #draw rectangle
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)

        #display
        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()

    def on_press(self, click):
        self.perform_press(click)
        self.notify_subscribers(click)


    def perform_press(self, click):
        x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
        zx1 = x1 - 0.01
        zy1 = y1 - 0.01
        zx2 = x1 + 0.01
        zy2 = y1 + 0.01
        self.rect.set_x(x1 - 0.01) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the X click point
        self.rect.set_y(y1 - 0.01) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the Y click point

        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.zoom_axes=[zx1,zx2,zy1,zy2]

    def notify_subscribers(self, click):
        for subscriber in self.subscriber_list:
            self.subscriber_list.get(subscriber)(click)

    # adds a new subscriber to the list. "name" is a subscriber identifier, "action" is called as "action(name)" every time this element is clicked
    def add_subscriber(self, name, action):
        self.subscriber_list[name]=action

    def on_notified(self, click):
        #Do something here
        #print("Zoom received notification from Zoom2: ", click)
        self.perform_press(click)


app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: that what i need I will try to understand the code thank you very much

Comment: I have a question why when I change the selected area in canvas both rectangles in zoom1 and zoom2 do not display yet ? thank you

Comment: They do, but they show at coordinates set by `x = y = 0.01` line, which is outside of the displayed area (set via `zoom_axes`). You can find it if you select an area close to left edge around middle height. Also you re-create Figure and Rectangle and everything every time you click first panel, but the old ones are never deleted, which may lead to a number of issues. You should either create them once and update or clear them on Update calls. I'll edit the answer to add a fix for that a bit later.

Comment: Well, if you still have questions you're welcome to ask them.

Comment: if you have any idea how can i connecte rectangle patch with dimensiosn5x5 to have all value 25 value inside rectangle using wxpython ? thank you this is my question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060490/how-i-can-show-25-values-of-pixels-in-matrix-5x5-of-rectangle-patch-using-wxpyth]